# What happen if i erased process dictionary of gen_server module?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server, process-dictionary

I was playing with the process dictionary inside a gen_server module, i called get() function and i get something like this.

```
{'$ancestors',[main_server,<0.30.0>]},
{'$initial_call',{child_server,init,1}}]
```

what happen if i erased the process dictionary, what would go wrong ?
i erased it and every thing worked fine, even
calling a function that generates an exception in the child_server the main_server still can get the exit signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ancestors` is used *only in the initialization stage*, to get the parent's PID, which is used to catch the `EXIT` message coming from the parent, so that the `terminate` stuff can get executed. Erasing this key when the server is up and running makes no difference.

`$initial_call`, on the other hand, is used in the crash report by `proc_lib` to dump the MFA info.

A quick `grep` in the OTP source tree can certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

I think some debug functions may use process dictionary, for example erlang:process_info/2